# Setup authenticated corporate proxy in Grunt server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, proxy, gruntjs

I am starting to work on an existing Angular JS application, however I am unable to get it working behind the corporate proxy.

In the application all the backend web service calls are redirected to the a differnt server (say https://servicesURL/api/) using proxy configuration in the Gruntfile.js. This works perfectly if I run the application outside my authenticated corporate proxy, however behind the proxy I see that all web service calls are failing with the error:

```
An error has occurred: {"code":"ENOTFOUND","errno":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"servicesURL","host":"servicesURL","port":443}
```

The grunt file proxy configuration is as below:

```
connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9005,
            hostname: 'localhost',
            useAvailablePort: true,
            livereload: 35712
        },
        proxies: [
            {

                context: ['/api'],
                host: 'serviceURL',
                port:443,
                https: true,
                xforward: true
            }
        ],
        livereload: {
            options: {
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect().use(
                            '/bower_components',
                            connect.static('./bower_components')
                        ),
                        connect.static(appConfig.app),
                        proxy
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
        }
```